# Title changed to: Issues with Mule JPA module

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-module-jpa

I am trying to integrate Hibernate with Mule. Does Mule support Hibernate Transport ?

Hi @David,

I have tried to work with Mule JPA module. But I am facing Below issues. Kindly help me.

**Here is my applicationContect.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <!-- Connection Pool -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory --> 
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
            p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="database" value="${jdbc.database}"/>
                    <property name="showSql" value="${jdbc.showSql}"/>      
            </bean>     
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
            p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes for eg @Autowired-->
    <context:annotation-config/>

      <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations  -->
      <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- Property Configurator -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="jdbc.properties"/>
    </bean>



    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.dao"/>

    <bean id="contactService" class="com.test.service.ContactServiceImpl"/>

</beans>
```

**and this is my mflow file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jpa http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jpa/current/mule-jpa.xsd">

  <spring:beans>
           <spring:import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml" />
    </spring:beans>


        <jpa:config name="Java_Persistence_API" entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" doc:name="Java Persistence API"/>
    <flow name="jpa-exampleFlow1" doc:name="jpa-exampleFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>

   <!-- code to be written -->
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

**this is my entity class**

```
package com.test.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import javax.persistence.*;
import com.test.vo.Contact;
import com.test.vo.ContactVO;

@Entity
@Table(name="contact")

public class ContactEO implements Contact{

    @Transient
    Contact contact;

    @Transient
    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public ContactEO(){
        contact = new ContactVO();
    }

    public ContactEO(Contact contact){
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return contact.getFirstName();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        contact.setFirstName(firstName);
    }

    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    public String getLastName() {
        return contact.getLastName();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        contact.setLastName(lastName);
    }

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    public String getEmail() {
        return contact.getEmail();
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        contact.setEmail(email);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    public long getId() {
        return contact.getId();
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        contact.setId(id);
    }



}
```

Getting below Exception Please let me know the solution.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: IllegalAccessError:
>   tried to access method org.hibernate.engine.CascadeStyle.()V
>   from class org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadeStyle$1    at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:219)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:127)
>   Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating
>   bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   org.hibernate.engine.CascadeStyle.()V from class
>   org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadeStyle$1
>   (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
>   (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
>     at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:207)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to
>   access method org.hibernate.engine.CascadeStyle.()V from class
>   org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadeStyle$1
>   (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to
>   access method org.hibernate.engine.CascadeStyle.()V from class
>   org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadeStyle$1   at
>   org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:117)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:119)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
>     ... 10 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access
>   method org.hibernate.engine.CascadeStyle.()V from class
>   org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadeStyle$1   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
>     at
>   org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access
>   method org.hibernate.engine.CascadeStyle.()V from class
>   org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadeStyle$1   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadeStyle$1.(EJB3CascadeStyle.java:24)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.EJB3CascadeStyle.(EJB3CascadeStyle.java:19)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:19)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.(EventListenerConfigurator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.(Ejb3Configuration.java:136)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:130)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
>     ... 24 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the JPA connector: http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors/jpa-connector ?

Comment: I have tried with JPA connecter  and faceing issues. kindly help me to solve the the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is now a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19952468/387927 ;) Check the answers over there :)

Comment: Thanks @DavidDossot. It helped a lot. I have one more question in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858446/mule-jpa-persist-is-not-inserting-or-updating