# Mule JPA module with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, mule

Trying to implement Mule module JPA with Hibernate in Mule and unable to persist data using . When I check in db, no values are inserted. I referred this link, but am unable to implement the solution given in this link, [Mule JPA persist is not inserting or updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858446/mule-jpa-persist-is-not-inserting-or-updating).

Could someone please elaborate or provide alternate suggestions on this? Thanks.

```
<code>
   <spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:Spring/applicationContext.xml" />
    </spring:beans>
       <spring:beans>
<spring:bean id="myBean" class="org.Location">
 </spring:bean>
     <spring:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          id="transactionManager">
        <spring:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </spring:bean>
 </spring:beans> 
   <jpa:config name="JPA" entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" doc:name="JPA"/>    
        <flow name="FlowParseJson">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/parseJSON" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <parse-template location="/jsonjpacheck" doc:name="Parse Template"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="org.Location" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <logger  message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="In Transaction"/>
    <transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
          <jpa:persist  entity-ref="#[payload]" config-ref="JPA" doc:name="Java Persistence API"/> 
    </transactional>
         <logger  message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="After Transaction"/>
        </flow>
</code>
```

And Persistence.xml

```
<code>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
          <class>org.Location</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxx" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxxx" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
</code>
```

And applicationcontext.xml,

```
<code>
      <context:spring-configured/>
            <context:annotation-config />
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean>
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                 <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
                  id="transactionManager">
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
            </bean>

           <bean id="sessionFactory" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory" factory-method="getSessionFactory"/>

            <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    </code>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code that is relevant to understand what you have tried.

Comment: I have edited it.  JPA is not persisting and no errors on compilation/runtime. Suggested custom-transaction, but please help on how to implement it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another alternative example [mule_spring_hibernate](https://github.com/NoelNightingale/mule_spring_hibernate_demo) . After long battles to get get the correct libraries working together I decided I needed to create a demo project and share

Please take note of the loader.override=org.hibernate entry in the mule-deploy.properties file.

Comment: Hey @Noel Nightingale, thanks for the answer, how does the loader.override work? I added this item, but now my deployments are failing with a null pointer exception for some reason

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider [persisting data via Hibernate from a Mule component](http://www.ricston.com/blog/jpa-mule/). Working example of this in Mule 3.6.1 may be found [here](https://github.com/gabrieldimech/mule-jpa-demo).